# GRMustache core data category not visible?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, mustache, template-engine, objective-c-category

I've a bunch of core data models 'NSManagedObject subclasses' with a couple of categories for each.
I want the template to use attributes from model's category, which is from what I understand is ok since:

```
[model valueForKey:@"attributeName"];
```

is actually returning the desired value!

BUT when I evaluate it in a mustache template it returns an empty string!!

so this code snippet is returning an empty string:

```
NSString *template = @"{{# experiences }}{{experienceElement}}{{/ experiences }}";
return [GRMustacheTemplate renderObject:self fromString:template error:nil];
```

where self is another model's category that has experiences as an attribute (NSSet) and experienceElement is a function that returns a string in Experience Model's category.

but it works when I replace experienceElement with a real attribute in the Experience model it self!

what is wrong on this implementation?

note: this is a cocoa mac app, using libGRMustache7-MacOS.a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from v 7.0.0 for the sake of [security](https://github.com/groue/GRMustache/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md#breaking-changes)

A new [safe key access](https://github.com/groue/GRMustache/blob/master/Guides/security.md#safe-key-access) constraint was introduced to limit keys to only class properties

A solution is to declare a read only property at the category with the name of the method

at category_file.h

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString * experienceElement
```

at category_file.m

```
-(NSString*) experienceElement
{
    NSString *newValue = @"";//derive new value
    return newValue; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I just didn't notice the key safety stuff. thanks for the fast reply and the great GRMustache.